# Altering data in Ext.data.Model

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Below are the two models I am having:

```
Ext.define('Company', {        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'company'},
        {name: 'price', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'change', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'pctChange', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'},
        {name: 'industry'},
        {name: 'desc'}
     ]
});

Ext.define('CompanyDemo', {        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'company'},
        {name: 'price', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'change', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'pctChange', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'},
        {name: 'total'}
     ]
});
```

These two models are associated with two different grids. I will select some rows from one grid (which is associated with Company model) and only the selected rows will be displayed in the second grid on a button click (which is associated with CompanyDemo model, initially this model is empty and does not have any data)

This is the grid with Company model:

```
var grid2 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {      id: 'grid2',
    store: getLocalStore(),
    selModel: sm,
    columns: [
        {text: "Company", width: 200, dataIndex: 'company'},
        {text: "Price", renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney, dataIndex: 'price'},
        {text: "Change", dataIndex: 'change'},
        {text: "% Change", dataIndex: 'pctChange'},
        {text: "Last Updated", width: 135, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), dataIndex: 'lastChange'},
        {text: "Industry", dataIndex: 'industry'},
        {text: "Description", dataIndex: 'desc'}
    ],
    columnLines: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    frame: true,
    title: 'Framed with Checkbox Selection and Horizontal Scrolling',
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    renderTo: 'grid'
});
```

I am able to get the selected data from this grid. After getting this data, I need to replace the Industry and Desc data and replace it with Total (Acording to the model structure given above). This is how I am getting the selected rows of the grid with Company model:

**EDIT:**

Tried with this bit of code:

```
Ext.widget('button', {
text: 'Click Me',   
renderTo: 'btn',
listeners: {
    click: function(this1, evnt, eOpts ){  
      var records = sm.getSelection();
      var data = [];
      Ext.each(records, function (record) {
        var modelData = record.getData(true);
        //A dummy value as of now
        modelData.total = '10';
        data.push(modelData);
      });
      // grid1.getStore().loadData(records, true);         
      grid1.getStore().loadData(data, true);
    }
}
});
```

but an exception is thrown in this line:

```
grid1.getStore().loadData(data, true);
```

I am not sure how to replace the two fields from 1st model and add new data in it before displaying it in the second grid.

Please let me know about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are giving the new grid the wrong data. It will be expecting an array of CompanyDemo model objects.

```
click: function(this1, evnt, eOpts ){  
    var records = sm.getSelection(),
        demoModels = [];

    // Iterate over the selected Company records
    Ext.each(records, function (record) {
        // Copy the data from the original Company model into the demo model
        var demoModel = new CompanyDemo(record.getData());
        demoModel.set('total', 10);

        demoModels.push(demoModel);
    });

    grid1.getStore().loadData(demoModels, true);
}
```